# How to draw spokes from the center of a polygon to it's boundary using R

Tags: r, polygon

Suppose we have a polygon with five vertices. The two coordinates of the vertices are-

```
>x=c(1,4,6,3,-2)

>y=c(1,1,5,9,4)
```

We define the centre of the polygon as the point (mean(x),mean(y)).

I am struggling to draw **spokes** from the centre of the polygon to the boundary of the polygon such that the spokes creates same angle in the centre (i.e., two neighbouring spokes create equal angle in the centre). I also want to have the all the points on the boundary of the polygon (red circle in the following plot) in orderly manner.

Here is a rough sample plot (convex) which I want to have:
[image]
**Note:** The polygon I am dealing with not necessarily convex.

Sample plot (non-convex)
[image]

**The output** I want: **1)** The coordinates of the line (i.e., the intersection points of the line through the origin and boundary segments of the polygon).
**2)** For each equispaced angle (theta in fig.2) I want a to draw a spoke corresponding to each theta (as in figure 2). Note that, angle lies between 0 to 360 degree.

**3)** In case of my second polygon (non-convex) where the same line go through two boundary segments (creating three intersecting points), I want to have three coordinates corresponding to the same angle (theta).

Could anyone help me in doing that using R? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will it always be a convex polygon? Will you add it onto an existing plot or is it acceptable to draw the spokes over the entire plot area and then mask outside the polygon with a white fill?

Comment: @Backlin Thanks for your attention. These polygon's not necessarily convex. You are correct to guess that I shall add it onto an exiting plot.  I also want to have all the intersecting points of the spokes and boundary of the polygon (red points). I added this point in my question.

Comment: I think the problem is quite a lot harder than what it appears like at a first glance. To get a reliable solution I suggest you check out stuff like the GIS tools for working with maps and geometry. It's far from my area of experise but perhaps [threads like this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93096/how-to-perform-a-true-gis-clip-of-polygons-layer-using-a-polygon-layer-in-r) could be a good place to start searching.

Comment: You are going to have to constrain your non-convex polygons in someway, and specify what you want to do for the various cases that can occur.
For example is this polygons with non-intersecting edges? And what to do in those kind of cases.
You will need to draw more pictures....

Comment: @MikeWise. Thanks for the suggestion. I added a plot for non-convex polygon. Hope this will clarify my aim.

Comment: What output do you want? Simply the coordinates of the lines? Or do you intend to build polygons from the sectors created? Also I notice in your concave polygon there's some lines to the low-right that go through two boundary segments. Do you want the spoke in this case to be made from two separate segments?

Comment: I added something to the pseudo-code to handle convex cases. But it would be a fair amount of work to write this in R (or most anything else).

Comment: @Spacedman. Thanks for raising these important points. I added these points to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. You need the sp and rgeos packages:

```
spokey <- function(xy,n=20){
    xcent = mean(xy[,1])
    ycent = mean(xy[,2])
    cent = sp::SpatialPoints(cbind(xcent, ycent))
    pts = sp::SpatialPoints(xy)
    ## take the furthest distance from centre to vertex, times two!
    r = 2 * max(sp::spDistsN1(pts, cent))
    theta=seq(0,2*pi,length=n+1)[-(n+1)]
    ## construct a big wheel of spoke lines
    sl = sp::SpatialLines(
        lapply(1:length(theta),function(id){
            t = theta[id]
            sp::Lines(
                list(
                    sp::Line(
                        rbind(
                            c(xcent, ycent),
                            c(xcent + r * cos(t),ycent + r * sin(t))
                            )
                        )
                    ),ID=id)
        }))
    ## construct the polygon as a SpatialPolygons object:
    pol = sp::SpatialPolygons(list(sp::Polygons(list(sp::Polygon(rbind(xy,xy[1,]))),ID=1)))
    ## overlay spokes on polygon as "SpatialLines" so we do line-on-line
    ## intersect which gets us points
    spokes = rgeos::gIntersection(sl, as(pol,"SpatialLines"), byid=TRUE)
    spokes
}
```

It takes a matrix of coordinates where the first point is not the last point:

```
xy1 = structure(c(4.49425847117117, 4.9161781929536, 7.95751618746858, 
7.92235621065338, 9.76825499345149, 9.9616348659351, 8.04541612950659, 
7.83445626861537, 6.42805719600729, 0.644241009906543, 2.40223985066665, 
1.24196061576498, 2.13854002455263, 7.935927470861, 9.41043173309254, 
9.33179150577352, 6.50074332228897, 7.34612576596839, 2.76533252463575, 
1.07456763727692, 3.88595576393172, 1.17286792142569, 2.745672467806, 
5.20317957152522, 5.81264133324759, 8.21116826647756), .Dim = c(13L, 
2L))
```

and then:

```
> plot(xy1,asp=1)
> polygon(xy1)
> spokes = spokey(xy1,20) # second arg is number of spokes
> points(spokes,pch=19,col="red")
```

gets you:

[image: spoke points]

If you don't believe it, draw the segments from the centre to the points :)

```
 segments(mean(xy1[,1]),mean(xy1[,2]), coordinates(spokes)[,1], coordinates(spokes)[,2])
```

The function `coordinates(spokes)` will get you a two-column matrix of the spoke points - its returned as a `SpatialPoints` object at present.

Comment: I have one more question: In the output is it true that the spokes are ordered with respect to the  increasing order of magnitude of theta (0 to 360 degree)?

Comment: Possibly, but what about when you have three points on a spoke like at the bottom right? The order might be preserved but I can't guarantee it. However you can easily compute the angle using `atan2(y-ymean, x-xmean)`  where `x` and `y` are the points and `xmean` and `ymean` are the centre of the spokes.

Comment: Ok...Just one observation: for the data set that you considered above,  the order is preserved even if when we have three points on a spoke. And for the use of atan function  one have to be careful about the magnitude of the angle, since it will report value with in (-pi/2,pi/2).

Comment: It may be late to ask this question but still I ask it because I could not resolved it. Though "coordinates(spokes)" is a two-column matrix but it is showing two more columns (apart from "x" and "y"), which are very important to me. Could you please suggest me how to get these first index columns (apart from "x" and "y") as another matrix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how can `coordinates(spokes)` show a two-column matrix but show two more columns? Is it a four-column matrix? If you run exactly my code (which is fully reproducible) do you get something else? If not, what are you doing that is different? What inputs are you feeding my function?

Comment: Sorry it may be confusing to use the word "column".  Let me explain what I am talking about. The output of the "coordinates(spokes)" with your given inputs, gives two "id" : first one consists of (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,18,19,20) and second one is a vector of 1, and the two columns are values of "x" and "y". A compilation of your answer code and use of "coordinates(spokes)" gives the output, that I am talking about. I want to save only the first "id"  in a separate vector.  Or I just want to save the "id" of spokes as a vector. How to do this?

Comment: Okay I see it now. These are the rownames of the coordinate matrix: `rownames(coordinates(spokes))`  - the following monster should get the first number as integer: `as.numeric(do.call(rbind,strsplit(rownames(coordinates(spokes))," "))[,1])`

Comment: This is exactly what, that  I wanted to have. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I modified this to handle the convex case illustrated.

You will have to write code that computes the intersection of a spoke from the center to each edge line segment. Not that hard, really, but have never seen it in R. Then you will have to loop over the angles that you are interested in drawing, loop over the segments, find the ones it intersects, sort those values, and then draw the line to the intersection you are interested in.
You would then to the furthest, or some combination (maybe a dotted line between the closest and the furthest).

In pseudo-code:

```
  for each spoke you want to draw
      calculate the spoke-line from the center to some point far outside
      initialize edge intersection-point list to empty
      for each edge-segment
          calculate the intersection-point of spoke-line and edge-segment
               if the intersection-point exists 
                  add it to the intersection list
      now go through the intersections and find the furthest
      draw the spoke from the center to the furthest intersection point
      continue with the next spoke
```

This would probably take several hours to research and write, unless you write this kind of graphics code constantly.

Comment: I thought of something on the same lines, but it will not behave correctly on all concave polygons, e.g. if the center is located outside of the polygon.

Comment: Right, I missed that. But then it is not really clear what he wants then, since they can get arbitrarily complex. He will have to constrain...

Comment: If the "centre" is outside a concave polygon I can still see how an algorithm like this would work, it just wouldn't have the "hub" visible. The `rgeos` package can easily clip lines to a polygon. But there's another clarification needed which I shall add in a comment to the Q...

Comment: Thank Mike Wise for your effort to solve my problem.