# Using Python, draw spokes from a polygon's center to its boundary

Tags: python

My problem is drawing spokes from the center of the polygon to the boundary so that each spoke creates the same angle.
I saw a comment mentioning the same idea in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979581/how-to-draw-spokes-from-the-center-of-a-polygon-to-its-boundary-using-r) post, but I'm not very experienced with coding in R. How can I implement it in Python?

So far, I have tried to convert it to python code, but I have no experience with R code and I could not understand how "sp::SpatialLines" constructs a wheel of spokes.
Can anyone help me to understand this code in python?

Here is my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

def spoke(coords, n=8):
  xc = (max(coords[:, 0])+min(coords[:, 0]))/2.
  yc = (max(coords[:, 1])+min(coords[:, 1]))/2.

  pts = pd.DataFrame(coords)
  #print(pts)

  dist = (abs(coords[:, 0] - xc) ** 2 + abs(coords[:, 1] - yc) ** 2) ** 0.5
  ## take the furthest distance from centre to vertex, times two!
  r = max(dist)
  #print("r = ", r)
  theta = np.linspace(start=0, stop=2*math.pi, num=n+1)
  
  result = []
  for i in range(1, len(theta)):
    cen = np.array((xc, yc)) 
    s_point = np.array((xc + r * np.cos(i), yc + r * np.sin(i)))
    center = pd.DataFrame([cen])
    s_points = pd.DataFrame([s_point])
    s1 = np.concatenate([center, s_points])
    result.append(s1)
    print("s1 = ", s1)

  return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
  poly = [(4.494258, 7.935927), (4.916178, 9.410432), (7.957516, 9.331792), (7.922356, 6.500743), (9.768255, 7.346126), 
        (9.961635, 2.765333), (8.045416, 1.074568), (7.834456, 3.885956), (6.428057, 1.172868), (0.644241, 2.745672),
        (2.402240, 5.203180), (1.241961, 5.812641), (2.138540, 8.211168)]
  poly_arr = np.array(poly)
  a = spoke(poly_arr)
  a = np.array(a)
  center = a[:, 0]
  points = a[:, 1]
  plt.figure()
  plt.scatter(poly_arr[:, 0], poly_arr[:, 1], c='r', marker='o', s=2)
  plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], c='b', marker='x', s=20)
  plt.plot(poly_arr[:, 0], poly_arr[:, 1], c='black', linewidth=1)
  plt.show()
```

[image: This] This is the result.

Comment: your loop iterates from a 0 angle to 360 degrees. Then you just need to draw a lne from the center to the intersecting point. The tricky part here is calculating the intersection point with the segments. Drawing a line is easy using matplotlib for example, you just need to do `plt.plot([xc, xf], [yc, yf])`  where `xc` `yc` are the center coordinates and `xf` `yf` are the intersection points

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Thank you for your help. I tried to calculate line segment but I failed. I think there is something wrong with calculation of theta. I have updated my post that shows the plot of my code. As you can see, the selected points are not on the polygon.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with an easy polygon (a triangle). Also post the coords you are using so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I added the coords of polygon and completed the code. I will try with simple one. Thank you.

Comment: I executed your code. Several imports are missing. Then you havent posted any code that plots the polygon and points (images cannot be copy pasted, so they are not reproducible examples). You need to post a code as text that copy pasting it will execute and show your problem. Also your points don't define a triangle as suggested. Is the triabgle working already? is a rectangle or a regular pentagon working? When it works we can move to irregular non convex polygons

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I added all the required for running the code. My apologize for that. This code it is not working with triangle, I am not sure how can I change it, but let me work on it.

Comment: it looks like you are just generating points around a circle of radius r.`s_point = np.array((xc + r * np.cos(i), yc + r * np.sin(i)))` You don't have any code to detect the crossing betwwen the polygon segment and the line from the center.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki You are right. I consider your point. Thanks